# Почему выводит пустые скобки без значений?

Tags: swift

господа. Мне понадобилось создать тюпл в котором я записал разные значения отжиманий, подтягиваний и приседаний. (Помещаю ниже):

```
var Tuple = (Pushups: 40, Pullups: 20, Squats: 30)

var (Push_ups, Pull_ups, Squ_ats) = Tuple
```

Задача вот в чём: мне нужно создать идентичный тюпл, с теми же параметрами, но с разными значениями. Нужно поменять в первом тюпле всё местами не назначая их(==), используя промежуточные переменные (var), чтобы я смог их изменить:

```
var friendTuple = (Pushups: 30, Pullups: 10, Squats: 40)

var (friPush_ups, friPull_ups, friSqu_ats) = friendTuple

(Push_ups = friPush_ups, Pull_ups = friPull_ups, Squ_ats = friSqu_ats)
```

Собственно, я это и попытался сделать, но последняя строка кода выводит мне такую вещь - `( (),(),() )` - вместо `(30, 10, 40)`. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного мутное отписание проблемы, но если я правильно Вас понял, то вот последняя строчка (вместо Вашей последней):

```
(Push_ups, Pull_ups, Squ_ats) = (friPush_ups, friPull_ups, friSqu_ats)
```

результат: 
(.0 30, .1 10, .2 40)

Можно еще вот так, хотя может это не совсем то, что Вам нужно :)

```
(Push_ups, Pull_ups, Squ_ats) = (friPush_ups, friPull_ups, friSqu_ats)
Tuple = (Push_ups, Pull_ups, Squ_ats)
```

результат:
Tuple = (Pushups 30, Pullups 10, Squats 40)